# Text going out of container - Supposed to be responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text

I'm working on a project in Bootstrap 3 and I'm having a little problem with the text in extra small view. The text is basically flowing out of its container, but it's meant to stick and break accordingly. I've tried breaking the text with different CSS properties, such as `word-wrap`, `word-break`, `text-wrap`. None of these worked.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Problem]

This is how the code looks like:

```
<div class="comments-area row">
    <div class="user-info col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 right">
        <img src="{{ S_AVATAR_PATH }}" height="75px" alt="Avatar" class="comment-avatar valign-top img-circle cream-thick-border" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1" style="width: 2%;"></div>
    <div class="comment-rag col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 left" style="padding: 0;">
        <div class="comment-content">
            <span class="small">
                Posted by <strong>Username</strong>
                <span class="grey">
                    &nbsp;/&nbsp;30 likes
                    &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;30 dislikes
                    &nbsp;/&nbsp;30 days ago
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="pipe-hide">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="comment-options">
                <span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
                <span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
                <span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>
            </span>
            <br />

            <span class="break">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fastidii dissentiunt et pro, pri eu rebum omnes nusquam, has et iudico facilis forensibus. In wisi facete deterruisset has. Eirmod option officiis vis ad, mea no dicta ornatus scriptorem, vim te primis option. Stet invenire vis te. Per at omnis commodo, quot debet recteque duo id. Ius aeterno ponderum platonem an. Reque deleniti ei cum. Ut probo liberavisse pri, graeci saperecommodo, quot debet recteque duo id. Ius aeterno ponderum platonem an. Reque deleniti ei cum.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the little `.break` class:

```
.break {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    word-break: break-all !important;
    text-wrap: suppress !important;
}
```

Why isn't Bootstrap taking care of breaking my text correctly? What's wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you provide link to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the CSS of the `comment-content`?

When I try it with a fix-width of the comment-content class, everything work great.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj2Uz/).